# Rails -- rename restful route

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I wanted to know what the easiest way to rename a restful route is.  Basically I have a controller called Employees and rather than have employees/new I want employees/hire to be used and achieve the same thing and make employees/new an invalid url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific need, the guide has exactly this example for new, edit, this should work:

```
resources :employees, :path_names => { :new => 'hire' }
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-the-new-and-edit-segments

Answer (score 0):

One of the best sources of data on routes is the rails guide:
[Rails Guide on Routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), also the command

```
rake routes
```

This command will show you all the current routes.

But in answer to this specification question
if you look into your routes file you can create new routes 
manually.

```
match 'employee/hire' => 'Employees#new', :via => :get, :as => 'employee_path'
```

the first argument matches what the browser is looking for.
The second argument is the controller and method.
The third is if it is a get, put, post, or delete call.
The fourth is the name for the path so you can access with the standard name_path type of call from code.

This makes sense?

Comment: Yes but you will want to test order for priority.  I can't remember off the top of my head if items later in the routes file take precedent or earlier ones.

Comment: This won't rename the route, just alias it.